# Conditional distribution of Ito's integral

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Suppose $\sigma=\sigma(t)$ is a deterministic process and $X(t)=\int_0^t \sigma(u)dW(u)$. I would like to compute the conditional distribution of $x(t)-x(s)$ given $\mathcal{F}_s$, where $0\leq s<t$. My intuition is that since 
$$X(t)-X(s)=\int_s^t \sigma(u)dW(u),$$
it should be that
$$\mathbb{E}[X(t)-X(s)|\mathcal{F}_s]=0$$
$$Var(X(t)-X(s)|\mathcal{F}_s)=\int_s^t\sigma(u)^2du$$
How can I prove such claim (if it is correct)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X(t)-X(s)$ is independent of $\mathcal F_s$. 
$$ E[(X(t)-X(s))^2] = E[X(t)^2-2X(t)X(s)+ X(s)^2]= E[X(t)^2] -2E[X(s)X(t)] +E[X(s)^2]= \int_0^t \sigma^2(u)du -2\int_0^s \sigma^2(u)du +\int_0^s \sigma^2(u)du=\int_s^t\sigma^2(u)du.  $$
Another way: since $X(t)-X(s)$ and $X(s)$ are independent
$$D^2(X(t))=D^2(X(t)-X(s)+X(s))= D^2(X(t)-X(s)) + D^2(X(s))$$ 
from which you get $$D^2(X(t)-X(s))= D^2(X(t))-D^2(X(s)).$$

Comment: How can we show that $X(t)-X(s)$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$? Could you clarify what does the notation $D^2$ mean?

Comment: $D^2$ is just the variance. You could just approximate $X(t)$ by Ito-sums and show that all the approximatig sums are independent of $\mathcal F_s$ and take the limit.